# I need cost for tickets purchased in August, 2019

Tags: airlines

Need to know how much next day economy tickets cost
on United 5357 (Calgary to ORD) and
United 670 (ORD to Boston)  if purchased 8/14/19.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question by anyone outside of the airline.

Comment: Look at your bank statements. (Only if you did buy one then. But that is the only way you can be certain that the price mentioned is the right one.)

Answer (score 1):

Prices often change during the day, depend on where you are located when booking, and there is no central repository of historical prices. Airlines do not publish this information either.
Therefore, there is no way to know the answer to your question, if it even exists.